# What SQL statement have to use to get list of non duplicate id's from 1 table, but 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Have a table for chat where I collect **`user_from`, `user_to`** and other non important stuffs for the example.

Want to get user_id's for all the users related in conversation (with where clause for current user_id).

In the example below I'm trying to search all the users where **`user_id=1`** exist, but I know that doesn't work and don't know how to make it works.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages M 
WHERE M.user_from="1" OR M.user_to="1" 
GROUP by m.user_from, m.user_to
```

If in table are rows (below). Actually I want to receive finally array([0]=>2, [1]=>4), because user_id=1 have conversation only with user_id=2 and user_id=4

```
user_from | user_to
1            2
1            2
2            1
1            4
3            2
```

Probably I have to use Select in the Select or use anykind of Case When Then, but have no idea how to loop it correctly

**RESOLVED WITH ORDERING BY LAST MSG_ID!!!**

```
SELECT (IF( user_from = 1, user_to, user_from )) as user_id
FROM messages
WHERE  `user_from` = 1 OR  `user_to` = 1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY MAX(msg_id) DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_to as user_id
from   messages
where  user_from = 1
union
(select user_from as user_id
from   messages
where  user_to = 1)
```

edited on suggestion from @Анжел Миленов - (I do not personally know why the brackets make a difference in mySql)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but something is not correctly at 100%, because now - gives me results only where user_from = 1 and not for user_to = 1 ...

Comment: I can't see a problem, you could check by running the first and second part of the `UNION` separately

Comment: While is between () works - 1 hour later solved it
`select user_to as user_id
from   messages
where  user_from = 1
union
(select user_from as user_id
from   messages
where  user_to = 1)`
Can you Edit it as second part between () to mark it as correct answer

Comment: Paul, how to order them DESC by msg_id

`msg_id, user_from, user_to`

Comment: Sorry, you can't order them by `msg_id` unless you added `msg_id` to the queries `select msg_id, user_to...` - then you'd need a whole different query

Comment: What do you mean by whole different query.
Have I to make 2 different queries and from the result of the first to do foreach loop for the second query?

Comment: Just think about what you're trying to do. You ask that the results be ordered by `msg_id`, but `msg_id` is not even in the query. If you add it in, then the `UNION DISTINCT` won't work as it does any more, and you'll get into a situation where you want the lowest `msg_id` per `user_id` which as I say, is a whole different query.

Comment: Yeah I know that it is not into the query, instead of making a new Topic. I've asked you just incase if you can tell me how to make ordering DESC includig msg_id into the query.